maximizing image display window before selecting points with plt.ginput()
This is probably something very simple, but I have wasted a day and more working on it, and am no closer to a solution.  I have a snippet of Python that:

opens an image file
calculates the FFT and shifts the origin
displays the FFT
allows user to mark points
operates on those points
draws results of the operations back to the FFT window

The details of steps 5 and 6 are irrelevant.  The FFT display opens in a small window that I can manually maximize in order to make the point marking more precise.
I am trying to automatically maximize the FFT display before I start marking points, but none of the approaches I have tried work.
Here is the code I have used:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('file.tif')                     # step 1

dft = np.fft.fft2(image)
dft = np.fft.fftshift(dft, axes=(-2,-1))           # step 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.log(np.abs(dft) ** 2))                # step 3

pts = plt.ginput(n = -1, timeout = -1,
      show_clicks = True, mouse_add = 1,
      mouse_pop = 2, mouse_stop = 3 )              # step 4

"""
[ manipulate pts data ]                            # step 5
[ draw things in FFT display with plt.plot() ]     # step 6
"""

plt.show()

I can maximize the window at the very end by inserting:
manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.full_screen_toggle()

just above plt.show(), but I want to maximize it before the plt.ginput() step.  Nothing I have tried impacts the size of the FFT display and allows everything else to proceed.  For example, I can insert the widow maximizing and plt.show() commands before the plt.ginput() call, but that seems to block the point marking completely.
